# PGSQL - Median Function - Error

Tags: postgresql, syntax-error, median

I want to find the median value of some data in pgsql. A quick google search told me that PGSQL 8.2 does not come with a median function. After some more searching I found this link 
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Median

which provides some information on how to write a custom median function. Here is the code I have so far

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_schema.final_median(anyarray) RETURNS float8 STRICT AS
        $$ 
        DECLARE
          cnt INTEGER;
        BEGIN
          cnt := (SELECT count(*) FROM unnest($1) val WHERE val IS NOT NULL);
          RETURN (SELECT avg(tmp.val)::float8 
                    FROM (SELECT val FROM unnest($1) val
                            WHERE val IS NOT NULL 
                            ORDER BY 1 
                            LIMIT 2 - MOD(cnt, 2) 
                            OFFSET CEIL(cnt/ 2.0) - 1
                          ) AS tmp
                 );
        END
        $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

        CREATE AGGREGATE my_schema.mymedian(anyelement) (
          SFUNC=array_append,
          STYPE=anyarray,
          FINALFUNC=my_schema.final_median,
          INITCOND='{}'
        );

-- I need this filter here. This is a place holder for a larger query    
    select my_schema.mymedian(id) filter (where id < 5)
    from my_schema.golf_data
```

However I am getting an error when I run the code

```
ERROR:  function my_schema.mymedian(numeric) is not defined as STRICT
LINE 27: select my_schema.mymedian(id) filter (where id < 5)
                ^
HINT:  The filter clause is only supported over functions defined as STRICT.
********** Error **********

ERROR: function my_schema.mymedian(numeric) is not defined as STRICT
SQL state: 0AM00
Hint: The filter clause is only supported over functions defined as STRICT.
Character: 661
```

I am guessing the interpreter wants me to add the keyword strict somewhere. But I am not sure where I need to make this change.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Interestingly, the `FILTER` clause will be available in 9.4: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES - Are you sure, you are using 8.2: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES ?

Comment: I ran the select version() and here is the output                                                    "PostgreSQL 8.2.15 (Greenplum Database 4.2.7.1 build 1) on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.4.2 compiled on Feb 13 2014 19:33:14"

Comment: It seems that is not postgresql at all: *The Greenplum Database builds on the foundations of open source database PostgreSQL.* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenplum#cite_ref-11

Answer (score 0):

This page indicates how to use the `STRICT` keyword and what it does:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-createfunction.html

So try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_schema.final_median(anyarray) RETURNS float8 STRICT AS
```

IMPORTANT: 
The impact of using `STRICT` is that if your input is `NULL` (In your case, if there are no records with `id < 5`) then the result will be ASSUMED to be `NULL` and the function will not be called.  So you need to be sure the place where you call it from can cope with that.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have updated my code to incorporate your suggestion but I still get the same error. Updates added to the original post